# Updating URL by using apscheduler to run a function

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm trying to update this URL so that the word can change (using the Oxford Dictionaries API)

```
url = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/' + language + '/' + word_id().lower()
```

to get the word_id I have created this function to create a random word

```
def choose_word():
    words_file = open('words.txt', 'r')
    all_words = words_file.read()
    words_file.close()
    all_words = all_words.split('\n')
    word = random.choice(all_words)
    return word
```

and set `word_id = choose_word`

I have then added in this and it seems to be working (I added a print statement to check, and it does run) but the word never updates on the front-end of my Flask application

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(choose_word, trigger='cron', hour='00', minute='00')
# Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

Basically, every 24 hours I'm trying to update the word using the Oxford Dictionaries API on my Flask application.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you want your web app, open in the browser window, to automatically show the page for the new word when this is updated.

For this, you need to write Javascript code which will update the page in the browser. There are LOTS of ways of doing this. It's not really a problem that Flask can solve.

One approach would be for your JS to keep fetching an URL from the Flask server, and do something when the data it returns changes. This is quite simple, and the only downside is that you have to refresh often if you want to update quickly. Eg. if you fetch the data once a minute, your page will update within a minute of changing the word.

Another approach is for the Flask server to use something like socketIO to keep a connection between the browser and the server open all the time, and send a message when the word changes. This is probably overkill for your needs.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking to do. So if I would want to run this only at say 00:00 every night, I would need to look into writing some JS to fetch the URL? Would that be something like https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ ?